# Will changing phone storage to EXT4 filesystem cause issues?

Tags: ext4

I've found out about the journaling features of EXT4.Will they prevent data loss if the usb cable gets unconnected?(the usb port doesn't hold cable well)

I've also seen a few benchmarks and EXT4 seems to be generally the fastest except in specific use case scenarios.

**Will changing phone storage to EXT4 filesystem cause issues?** (I want to do this with removable sdcard as well)

I have Android 4.4.2 FWIW